# Fatal Error U1073: Don't know how to make 'f2c.h0'

Tags: c, visual-studio, nmake

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@chintanp/using-f2c-on-windows-to-convert-f77-files-to-c-33da825d5de0) and I am stuck on step 2 of building the library.

I have visual studio 2022 community edition installed and when I run the command `nmake -f makefile.vc all` I get back the error `NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'f2c.h0' Stop.`

I have checked that `f2c.h0` exists in my folder and it does so I am wondering what else I can try. Any suggestions appreciated.

Here is a portion of `makefile.vc`:

```
 CC = cl
CFLAGS = -DUSE_CLOCK -DMSDOS -DNO_ONEXIT -Ot1 -DNO_My_ctype -DNO_ISATTY

.c.obj:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c

w = \
    abort_.obj \
    backspac.obj \
    c_abs.obj \
    c_cos.obj \
    c_div.obj \
    c_exp.obj \
    c_log.obj \
    c_sin.obj \
    c_sqrt.obj \
    cabs.obj \
    close.obj \
    d_abs.obj \
    d_acos.obj \
    d_asin.obj \
    d_atan.obj \
    d_atn2.obj \
    d_cnjg.obj \
    d_cos.obj \
    d_cosh.obj \
    d_dim.obj \
    d_exp.obj \
    d_imag.obj \
    d_int.obj \
    d_lg10.obj \
    d_log.obj \
    d_mod.obj \
    d_nint.obj \
    d_prod.obj \
    d_sign.obj \
    d_sin.obj \
    d_sinh.obj \
    d_sqrt.obj \
    d_tan.obj \
    d_tanh.obj \
    derf_.obj \
    derfc_.obj \
    dfe.obj \
    dolio.obj \
    dtime_.obj \
    due.obj \
    ef1asc_.obj \
    ef1cmc_.obj \
    endfile.obj \
    erf_.obj \
    erfc_.obj \
    err.obj \
    etime_.obj \
    exit_.obj \
    f77_aloc.obj \
    f77vers.obj \
    fmt.obj \
    fmtlib.obj \
    ftell_.obj \
    getarg_.obj \
    getenv_.obj \
    h_abs.obj \
    h_dim.obj \
    h_dnnt.obj \
    h_indx.obj \
    h_len.obj \
    h_mod.obj \
    h_nint.obj \
    h_sign.obj \
    hl_ge.obj \
    hl_gt.obj \
    hl_le.obj \
    hl_lt.obj \
    i77vers.obj \
    i_abs.obj \
    i_dim.obj \
    i_dnnt.obj \
    i_indx.obj \
    i_len.obj \
    i_mod.obj \
    i_nint.obj \
    i_sign.obj \
    iargc_.obj \
    iio.obj \
    ilnw.obj \
    inquire.obj \
    l_ge.obj \
    l_gt.obj \
    l_le.obj \
    l_lt.obj \
    lbitbits.obj \
    lbitshft.obj \
    lread.obj \
    lwrite.obj \
    main.obj \
    open.obj \
    pow_ci.obj \
    pow_dd.obj \
    pow_di.obj \
    pow_hh.obj \
    pow_ii.obj \
    pow_ri.obj \
    pow_zi.obj \
    pow_zz.obj \
    r_abs.obj \
    r_acos.obj \
    r_asin.obj \
    r_atan.obj \
    r_atn2.obj \
    r_cnjg.obj \
    r_cos.obj \
    r_cosh.obj \
    r_dim.obj \
    r_exp.obj \
    r_imag.obj \
    r_int.obj \
    r_lg10.obj \
    r_log.obj \
    r_mod.obj \
    r_nint.obj \
    r_sign.obj \
    r_sin.obj \
    r_sinh.obj \
    r_sqrt.obj \
    r_tan.obj \
    r_tanh.obj \
    rdfmt.obj \
    rewind.obj \
    rsfe.obj \
    rsli.obj \
    rsne.obj \
    s_cat.obj \
    s_cmp.obj \
    s_copy.obj \
    s_paus.obj \
    s_rnge.obj \
    s_stop.obj \
    sfe.obj \
    sig_die.obj \
    signal_.obj \
    sue.obj \
    system_.obj \
    typesize.obj \
    uio.obj \
    uninit.obj \
    util.obj \
    wref.obj \
    wrtfmt.obj \
    wsfe.obj \
    wsle.obj \
    wsne.obj \
    xwsne.obj \
    z_abs.obj \
    z_cos.obj \
    z_div.obj \
    z_exp.obj \
    z_log.obj \
    z_sin.obj \
    z_sqrt.obj

all: f2c.h math.h signal1.h sysdep1.h vcf2c.lib

f2c.h: f2c.h0
    copy f2c.h0 f2c.h
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question how exactly you follow the tutorial. What file(s) are you trying to compile? Show the contents of a (minimized) `makefile.vc`. Maybe the Makefile instructs `nmake` to look for the file at a different location.

Comment: The make works correctly if the `make/nmake` command is run from the command line in the same directory that the files from the `.zip` were extracted to [on linux, at least, with `make -f makefile.u`]. When run under visual studio, does it start the make in the correct directory? Try running `nmake -f makefile.vc` manually from a command prompt or powershell.

Comment: @CraigEstey That was exactly it. Once I changed directories from the default where visual studio developer command prompt started to the directory containing `makefile.vc` it worked. Thank you! Feel free to post that as an answer and I can accept if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build works correctly if the `make/nmake` command is run from the command line in the *same* directory that the files from the `.zip` were extracted to [on linux, at least, with `make -f makefile.u`].

When run under visual studio, does it start the build in the correct directory?

Try running `nmake -f makefile.vc` manually from a command prompt or powershell.

If that works, this means that visual studio must be configured to start with the correct directory.